Difficulty in finding the right parameter for cX and cY in my OMR project
OMR detection in stackedimages
this is the output of my python code
this is the main code
import cv2
import numpy as np
import utiliss

#######################
path = "omr_sheetF2.jpg"
heightImg=600
widthImg=600
questions=10
choices=5
ans = [0,2,1,4,5,0,3,2,2,1]
#######################

img = cv2.imread(path)

#Preprocessing
img = cv2.resize(img,(widthImg,heightImg))
imgContours = img.copy()
imgBiggestcontours = img.copy()
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray,(5,5),1)
imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgBlur,10,50)

#Finding  countours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgCanny,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(imgContours,contours,-1,(0,255,0),10)
#Finding Rectangles
rectcon = utiliss.rectcontours(contours)
biggestcontour = utiliss.getcornerpoints(rectcon[0])
gradepoints = utiliss.getcornerpoints(rectcon[2])
#print(biggestcontour)

if biggestcontour.size !=0 and gradepoints.size !=0:
    cv2.drawContours(imgBiggestcontours,biggestcontour,-1,(0,255,0),15)
    cv2.drawContours(imgBiggestcontours,gradepoints,-1,(255,0,0),15)

    biggestcontour= utiliss.reorder(biggestcontour)
    gradepoints = utiliss.reorder(gradepoints)

    pt1 = np.float32(biggestcontour)
    pt2 = np.float32([[0,0],[widthImg,0],[0,heightImg],[widthImg,heightImg]])
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pt1,pt2)
    imgWarpcolored= cv2.warpPerspective(img,matrix,(widthImg,heightImg))

    ptG1 = np.float32(gradepoints)
    ptG2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [325, 0], [0, 150], [325, 150]])
    matrixG = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ptG1, ptG2)
    imgGradeDisplay = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrixG, (325, 150))
    #cv2.imshow("Grade",imgGradeDisplay)

    #Applying Threshold
    imgWarpGray= cv2.cvtColor(imgWarpcolored,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    imgThresh= cv2.threshold(imgWarpGray,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

    boxes= utiliss.splitboxes(imgThresh)
    #cv2.imshow("test",boxes[37])
    #print(cv2.countNonZero(boxes[7]),cv2.countNonZero(boxes[0]))

    #Obtaining non zero pixel values of each box
    myPixelVal= np.zeros((questions,choices))
    countC= 0
    countR= 0

    for image in boxes:
        totalpixels = cv2.countNonZero(image)
        myPixelVal[countR][countC] = totalpixels
        countC +=1
        if (countC == choices):countR +=1 ;countC=0
        #print(myPixelVal)

    #Finding Index Values of the markings
    myIndex = []
    for x in range (0,questions):
        arr = myPixelVal[x]
        #print("arr",arr)
        myIndexVal = np.where(arr==np.amax(arr))
        #print(myIndexVal[0])
        myIndex.append(myIndexVal[0][0])
    #print(myIndex)

    #GRADING
    grading=[]
    for x in range(0,questions):
        if ans [x]== myIndex[x]:
            grading.append(1)
        else:grading.append(0)
    #print(grading)
    score= (sum(grading)/questions) *100 #FINAL GRADE
    print(score)

    #Displaying Answers
    imgResult = imgWarpcolored.copy()
    imgResult = utiliss.showanswers(imgResult,myIndex,grading,ans,questions,choices)


imgBlank = np.zeros_like(img)
imageArray = ([img,imgGray,imgBlur,imgCanny],
              [imgContours,imgBiggestcontours,imgWarpcolored,imgThresh],
              [imgResult,imgBlank,imgBlank,imgBlank])
imgStacked = utiliss.stackImages (imageArray,0.25)

cv2.imshow("Stacked Images",imgStacked)
cv2.waitKey(0)

this code is for utilities(utiliss) where it's functions are called to from the aforementioned
import cv2
import numpy as np

## TO STACK ALL THE IMAGES IN ONE WINDOW
def stackImages(imgArray,scale,lables=[]):
    rows = len(imgArray)
    cols = len(imgArray[0])
    rowsAvailable = isinstance(imgArray[0], list)
    width = imgArray[0][0].shape[1]
    height = imgArray[0][0].shape[0]
    if rowsAvailable:
        for x in range ( 0, rows):
            for y in range(0, cols):
                imgArray[x][y] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x][y], (0, 0), None, scale, scale)
                if len(imgArray[x][y].shape) == 2: imgArray[x][y]= cv2.cvtColor( imgArray[x][y], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        imageBlank = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
        hor = [imageBlank]*rows
        hor_con = [imageBlank]*rows
        for x in range(0, rows):
            hor[x] = np.hstack(imgArray[x])
            hor_con[x] = np.concatenate(imgArray[x])
        ver = np.vstack(hor)
        ver_con = np.concatenate(hor)
    else:
        for x in range(0, rows):
            imgArray[x] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x], (0, 0), None, scale, scale)
            if len(imgArray[x].shape) == 2: imgArray[x] = cv2.cvtColor(imgArray[x], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        hor= np.hstack(imgArray)
        hor_con= np.concatenate(imgArray)
        ver = hor
    if len(lables) != 0:
        eachImgWidth= int(ver.shape[1] / cols)
        eachImgHeight = int(ver.shape[0] / rows)
        #print(eachImgHeight)
        for d in range(0, rows):
            for c in range (0,cols):
                cv2.rectangle(ver,(c*eachImgWidth,eachImgHeight*d),(c*eachImgWidth+len(lables[d][c])*13+27,30+eachImgHeight*d),(255,255,255),cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(ver,lables[d][c],(eachImgWidth*c+10,eachImgHeight*d+20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.7,(255,0,255),2)
    return ver

def rectcontours(contours):

    rectcon=[]
    for i in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(i)
        #print("Area",area)
        if area>50:
            peri = cv2.arcLength(i,True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(i,0.02*peri,True)
            #print("corner point",len(approx))
            if len(approx)==4:
                rectcon.append(i)
    #print(rectcon)
    rectcon = sorted(rectcon,key= cv2.contourArea,reverse=True)

    return rectcon

def getcornerpoints(cont):
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cont, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cont, 0.02 * peri, True)
    return approx

def reorder(myPoints):

    myPoints = myPoints.reshape((4,2))
    myPointsNew = np.zeros((4,1,2),np.int32)
    add = myPoints.sum (1)
    #print(myPoints)
    #print(add)
    myPointsNew[0]= myPoints[np.argmin(add)] #[0, 0]
    myPointsNew[3]= myPoints[np.argmax(add)] #[w, h]
    diff = np.diff(myPoints,axis=1)
    myPointsNew[1]= myPoints[np.argmin(diff)] # [w, 0]
    myPointsNew[2]= myPoints[np.argmax(diff)] # [0, h]
    #print(diff)

    return myPointsNew

def splitboxes(img):
    rows= np.vsplit(img,10)
    boxes = []

    for r in rows:
        cols= np.hsplit(r,5)
        for box in cols:
            boxes.append(box)
            #cv2.imshow("split",box)
    return boxes
def showanswers(img,myIndex,grading,ans,questions,choices):
    secW= int(img.shape[1]/questions)
    secH= int(img.shape[1]/choices)

    for x in range (0, questions):
        myAns = myIndex[x]
        cX = (myAns*secW)+ secW//2
        cY = (x*secH)+ secH//2

        print(f"Iteration {x + 1}: myAns={myAns}, cX={cX}, cY={cY}")

        cv2.circle(img,(cX,cY),20,(0,255,0),cv2.FILLED)

    return img

from the utiliss code we can see that the value of cX and cY is what creating green circle on the last image in the output of stacked images but the aim is to create green circles in the shaded part of the omr sheet
output of main and utiliss code
tried changing the value of cX and cY to see if i could get the green circle on shaded part only and it didnt work
it's showing 5 circle instead of 10 and not on expected shaded part

Hey, interesting question. However, it would be better to narrow it down to your specific problem. E.g., since you are having a problem with cx and cy, only include that relevant code and relevant source images so others can easily reproduce your problem

Please do not show images of code. Also show individual images for your work.

too much code, please reduce to this:
minimal reproducible example
